# Google fusion table doesn't show all rows in scatter plot

Tags: plot, google-fusion-tables

I'm building a simple webapp that will display different charts about relationships between income and health.  I'm trying to use Google Fusion Tables to generate the charts, but I've hit a snag.  I have 807 rows in a chart and am trying to make a scatter plot between two columns.

It says all rows are being displayed, but the chart clearly doesn't have all of the data points.  How can I get all of the points to display?

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: Is this a public table? Can you provide a link to your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charts in Fusion Tables are limited to 500 data points. When the count goes above that the scatter chart uses a sampling algorithm to trim the data to that limit. This should be indicated on the chart; I've filed a bug for that.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if the trimming algorithm they use buried in the docs somewhere?